# Rotating MKMapKit

Tags: mkmapview, rotation, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am attempting to rotate an MKMapView using MapKit.

I can display a map and rotate it, however not very efficiently. I create an MKMapView larger than the view and rotate it using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation, so the the grey areas behind the view are not visible. Although I have clip subviews checked in Interface Builder, I still have the feeling this is not the correct implementation.

This method does allow me to rotate any annotations displayed as MKPinAnnotationView conforms to the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation function, but I come into problems when trying to add an overlay to the map.

I can place an overlay on using the boundingMapRect property in the class declaration but the image remains unrotated on the display. Is there a way to achieve this? Or alternatively should I be rotating the MKMapView and annotations in a different method?

Thanks in advance for any advice or information.

Answer (score 2):

Are you rotating the map so that it is facing the same way the user is? (i.e. not just North = Up). If so you don't need to do any transformation stuff at all, just set the MKUserTrackingMode to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading